# Element after jquery.show and WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My **javascript** line:

```
$('#name').show();
```

My **webdriver** code line:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("name"))).sendKeys("Some Name");
```

When I run the test it throws the following exception:

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

So, I have been searching for a solution. There are some issues reported in chromium google code site. There are a lot of suggestions about using `JavaScriptExecutor`. But it doesn't seem a better solution for me, because it could make a browser dependent code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After some hours I finally found a solution by using Actions without JavascriptExecuter:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(website);
actions.click();
actions.sendKeys("Some Name");
actions.build().perform();
```

Well, it worked for me. However, is this way the better solution ?

Answer (score 12):

A bit late to the party, but those looking for a solution to this problem while using selenium under python can use the following code:

```
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(my_div)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys("Some name") # Replace with whichever keys you want.
actions.perform()
```

Where `my_div` is an element you've previously selected, perhaps with code like this:

```
my_div = item.find_element_by_css_selector("div.foobar")
```

Comment: just to clarify, this answer worked for me in Python 3.5, I think the accepted solution is in Java

Answer (score 7):

On the similar lines if you are using protractor (angularjs) you can use it this way `

```
actions = protractor.getInstance().actions();
actions.mouseMove(element);
actions.click();
actions.sendKeys("Some text");
actions.perform();`
```