# How to get protractor to click inside a search box?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, protractor

I want to be able to click inside a search box which is on the page and then click submit and have a couple `expect` statements.
So far I have this:

```
it('should redirect to the correct page', function(){
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('header-search')).click();
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('header-search')).sendKeys("aaa");
    //element.all(by.id('header-search')).sendKeys("tfgm");
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:8080/web/customer/account");
});
```

When I run protractor all it does is click on the box but does not paste in the text.  Anyone have any ideas about what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at Elementor([Elementor Github Repo Here](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor)) to help you figure out what elements to call.

When you get it installed, there is a bug([Link to issue](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor/issues/7)) that currently is active, however it will still find your elements for you(gives you the by.id/by.css/by.buttonText) for you to plug into your tests.

Keep in mind that when you start Elementor, it will open a NEW instance of Chrome. You will need to duplicate the chrome tab before using the Elementor plugin(right click the tab> Duplicate).

As for your tests, you shouldn't NEED to click the search element. .sendKeys() will essentially "click" that element. The way to think of how sendKeys() works is it finds the element you specify, then will plug in the keys you state into that element.

I would suggest trying to change your statement to be:

```
this.headerSearch = by.id('headerSearch'); //Or any by.something element

it('should redirect to the correct page', function() {
  element(this.headerSearch).sendKeys("aaa\n"); // the \n will represent the "enter key"
});
```

You could go even further to parameterize the test and separate out your statements to follow the Page Object test methodology a bit better by doing:

This set of code will be in a PO file named something like SearchPage.js(remember the file needs to be exported):

```
this.headerSearch = by.id('headerSearch');

  this.setHeaderSearch = function(search) {
    element(this.headerSearch).sendKeys(search);
  };
```

This will be in your main test(it will need to import your SearchPage.js page object file):

```
it('should do something like input keys into element', function(){
    searchPO.setHeaderSearch('send some keys\n'); // the \n will represent the "enter key"
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:8080/web/customer/account");
  });
```

If you could provide everyone the HTML of the element your testing, we could help you out better.

I hope this was somewhat helpful to you!

Comment: I hope i was helpful. If i was at least helpful I could use a + rep. If this seemed to solve your issue, please mark my answer as solved!

Comment: sorry, only just seen this.
There must be a simple way to do this that doesn't require any of that duplicating of windows surely?
all i want is a simple it test that runs and clicks inside the element, sends keys and then searches. currently it says it cant focus the element. i tried your method like so `iit('should redirect to the correct page', function(){
  this.headerSearch = by.id('header-search');
  element(this.headerSearch).sendKeys("hello");
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:8080/web/tf_customer/my-account");
  });` but it  gave the error `cant focus element`

Comment: I would definitely recommend giving Elementor a shot(links above) to find your elements. If you could provide a code snippet, they i may be able to trouble shoot whats up with the error. Have you tried using by.model, or by.xpath yet?

Comment: Are you able to give us the code your working with? I'd like to really assist you with this.

Comment: problem has been solved, thanks.
will mark your answer as correct as gave me best help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to click the search field before entering keys, you can do that directly.
If the user is supposed to click a submit button after entering their search terms, don't forget to make protractor click it:

```
it('should redirect to the correct page', function(){
    element(by.id('header-search')).sendKeys('foo');
    $('[type="submit"]').click();
    //Expect-statements
});
```

Comment: i have tried commenting out the line that uses the `click()` and it still is giving me the same error. `unknown error: cannot focus element`. and I want to get `sendkeys()` working first before I click the button

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123539/element-after-jquery-show-and-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-focus-el/25342211#25342211 ? This seems to be worth looking into.

Comment: just had a little look. don't get how the actions part works though. as in, how do you access the individual actual element? i.e. where do you include `by.id` and such

Comment: It just seems to be an issue with Chrome, rendering it unable to access certain elements. If the issue persists, try running your test with Mozilla.

Comment: do you know where to change the browser it uses? is it in the conf.js?

Comment: Yes, the conf.js hold the run configuration for your tests. Look for the line : capabilities: {browserName: 'chrome'} and change it to capabilities: {browserName: 'firefox'}

Comment: right this is my conf.js file `exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};` and i added in firefox like so `exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {browserName: 'chrome'} and change it to capabilities: {browserName: 'firefox'} 
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};`. In chrome i had 47 tests, 1 failure, simply changed it went to 47 tests 38 failures..lol Wut?

Comment: Did you copy the entire line including my text? This should be your conf.js in total: 

https://jsfiddle.net/mugervf9/

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using with protractor? If you are using Firefox, this should be an issue. `sendKeys`cannot work on Firefox browser.

Comment: i am using chrome and it clicks inside the box but does not sendKeys(). how can one make chrome work?