# Unable to select Bootstrap dropdown in Java Selenium

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a very difficult time selecting bootstrap dropdown in Selenium.

I'm new to Selenium so any suggestion and guidance would be very helpful, as what I'd love to do is just select the dropdown, type "email", and press enter during the instance.

I've gone through dozens of solutions, but none of them have worked for this specific issue.

What can I do? Please help.

Salenium

```html
package newPackage;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


public class importLeads {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\David\\Downloads\\Notes\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //login to site
    driver.get("https://demos5.softaculous.com/Mautic/s/contacts/import/new");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //importing Data
    WebElement uploadBox = driver.findElement(By.id("lead_import_file"));
    uploadBox.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\David\\Downloads\\data_file.csv");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lead_import_start")).click();

    //Select from dropdown
    WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('lead_field_import_email_address')"));
    Actions cursor = new Actions(driver);
    cursor.moveToElement(dropdownToggle);
    cursor.click();
    cursor.perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement weh = driver.findElement(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address_chosen"));

    Actions cursor2 = new Actions(driver);
    cursor2.moveToElement(weh);
    cursor2.click();

 }
}
```

---

Here is the link to the data file [ufile.io/vy2ws](https://ufile.io/vy2ws)

In order for the upload of the .CSV file to work, you must be running a local version of this software. Download can be found here: https://www.mautic.org/m/asset/54:mautic-2100

Once uploaded, it should look like this where it asks to choose from the drop-down.

[image]

HTML

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
         <label class="control-label" for="lead_field_import_email_address">Email address</label>        
         <div class="choice-wrapper">
            <select id="lead_field_import_email_address" name="lead_field_import[email_address]" class="form-control" autocomplete="false" style="display: none;">
               <option value=""></option>
               <optgroup label="Contact">
                  <option value="email">Email</option>
               </optgroup>
            </select>
            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="width: 100%;" title="" id="lead_field_import_email_address_chosen">
               <a class="chosen-single chosen-default">
                  <span>Choose one...</span>
                  <div><b></b></div>
               </a>
               <div class="chosen-drop">
                  <div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div>
                  <ul class="chosen-results">
                     <li class="group-result">Contact</li>
                     <li class="active-result group-option" data-option-array-index="9" style="">Email</li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

Replacing :

```
WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('lead_field_import_email_add‌​ress')"));
```

to this :

```
WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address"))‌​;
```

resulted in:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 35535
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 22, 2017 1:20:49 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"lead_field_import_email_address"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'DAVID-PC', ip: '192.235.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f), userDataDir=C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4068_28713}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=61.0.3163.100, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: ee90469095e7b1121dc2e387d8e485e6
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=lead_field_import_email_address}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at newPackage.importLeads.main(importLeads.java:31)
```

---

Replacing

```
WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('lead_field_import_email_address')"));
    Actions cursor = new Actions(driver);
```

with

```
WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address"));
    Select select = new Select(element);
```

resulted in:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 32443
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 23, 2017 1:36:09 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"lead_field_import_email_address"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'HOME-PC', ip: '192.235.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f), userDataDir=C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\1\scoped_dir5416_25737}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=61.0.3163.100, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 40cde314a5a76400aceff8b625b38e3c
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=lead_field_import_email_address}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at newAutomation.importLeads.main(importLeads.java:33)
```

---

Comment: Can you share your Selenium code? Also, can you please format your HTML code, aligning it and, if possible laving just the part that is important for your problem?

Comment: Can you post your code what did you tried so far So we can point out whats wrong with your code. If possible then please share the site URL

Comment: I'm updated the code to be more simple and straight forward. The link I am using is https://demos5.softaculous.com/Mautic/s/contacts/import/new

Comment: @JamesRocky what's the content of your data_file.csv file?

Comment: @Durden the content of the data file includes only one column named "Email address" and multiple rows containing said email addresses

Comment: @JamesRockybut what's exactly the format? I try, following your code, to upload a file but after nothing happen

Comment: @Durden - here is the link to the data file https://ufile.io/vy2ws

Comment: @Tom I've added the code, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I would guess, after a quick look, that your selector is not right. Can you try to change from this `WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('lead_field_import_email_address')"));` to this `WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address"));`? Also, if there's any exception being thrown, include it in the question.

Comment: @Tom Thank you for the suggestion. I've updated the code to show what I've gotten when I've updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `HTML` you have provided, the **`WebElement`** with `id="lead_field_import_email_address"` is with in a **`Select`** tag. So instead of using **`Actions`** Class in this case we should try to use the `Select` Class instead as follows:

```
WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address"));
Select select = new Select(element);
```

Next, we can select any of the `options` by invoking either `selectByIndex(n)`, `selectByValue("value")` or `selectByVisibleText("visible_text")` method.

Comment: It seems as though when I try and implement it, it doesn't get selected

Comment: @JamesRocky My Answer is to help you with the Select Class. It must work without any failure. Which option are you trying to select? What is the error you are seeing? Can you update the Question with your current code & full error stack trace?

Comment: I had a lok at the url but I am not sure after uploading the file what exactly you are trying to do here `WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('lead_field_import_email_address')"));`. As there is no such element identified by the locator, you are seeing `NoSuchElementException`. Please update your exact manual step in the Question area.

Comment: I've updated the post to include what it should be showing once it is uploaded. It seems as though after carefully checking, that service doesn't upload it correctly. The one I am running is on a local machine, so you can download the software and test it from there as it does upload and prompt you to choose from the drop-down: https://www.mautic.org/m/asset/54:mautic-2100

Answer (score 3):

I tried to replicate manually the steps of your code but when I load the `data_file.csv` and I click the Upload button:

[image]

nothing happens.

And, in the html, there isn't the element that you try to find:

```
WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('lead_field_import_email_address')"));
```

That's why I wrote [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859941/unable-to-select-bootstrap-dropdown-in-java-selenium#comment80674648_46859941).

I can imagine that should open something. From the informations:

- Limit
- Delimiter
- Enclosure
- Escape

I can suppose that you have to upload a file with a particular format.

**EDIT**

Trying locally it works.
I don't understand well this part of your code:

```
        //Select from dropdown
        WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('lead_field_import_email_address')"));
        Actions cursor = new Actions(driver);
        cursor.moveToElement(dropdownToggle);
        cursor.click();
        cursor.perform();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement weh = driver.findElement(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address_chosen"));

        Actions cursor2 = new Actions(driver);
        cursor2.moveToElement(weh);
        cursor2.click();
```

If you want to choose from the email drop-down, you could use the xpath:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='choice-wrapper']//div[@id='lead_field_import_email_address_chosen']"));
```

or simply the id:

```
WebElement we= driver.findElement(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address_chosen"));
```

and execute the interested operation.

So, for example:

```
    WebElement we= driver.findElement(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address_chosen"));
    we.click();
    we.sendKeys("email");
    we.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

**EDIT 2**

Your problem is that you use **`Thread.sleep(XXXX);`** in order to wait the elements. This is not deterministic. You must use an **explicit wait**.

From [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

> An explicit wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition
>   to occur before proceeding further in the code. The extreme case of
>   this is time.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period
>   to wait. There are some convenience methods provided that help you
>   write code that will wait only as long as required. WebDriverWait in
>   combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this can be
>   accomplished.

So, in java you need:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
WebElement we=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address_chosen")));
```

Always from the previous link:

> This waits up to 15 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException unless
>   it finds the element to return within 15 seconds. WebDriverWait by
>   default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it
>   returns successfully. A successful return is for ExpectedCondition
>   type is Boolean return true or not null return value for all other
>   ExpectedCondition types.

Finally, the entire code:

```
        String geckoDriver = System.getProperty("pathTo/geckodriver";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriver);
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost:8888/2.10.0/s/contacts/import/new");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

        WebElement uploadBox=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lead_import_file")));
        uploadBox.sendKeys("/pathTo/data_file.csv");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lead_import_start")).click();

        //Select from dropdown
        WebElement we=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address_chosen")));
        we.click();
        we.sendKeys("email");
        we.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

**EDIT 3**

With Firefox, the above code (in my tests) is ok. I noticed that you use Chrome. With Chrome, I have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123539/element-after-jquery-show-and-webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-focus-el). The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21123540/3881320) works for me:

```
        //Select from dropdown
        WebElement we=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lead_field_import_email_address_chosen")));
        /*we.click();
        we.sendKeys("email");*/

        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(we);
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys("email");
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        actions.build().perform();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I just noticed that uploading a .CSV file doesn't work on that. I'm actually running a local version of that service and it should work. You can download the software here and run it locally: https://www.mautic.org/m/asset/54:mautic-2100

Comment: Has this worked for you? I've tried this and sadly it didn't result in selection of the drop down and gave this error `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='choice-wrapper']//div[@id='lead_field_import_email_address_chosen']"}`

Comment: Using the id resulted in this error `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"lead_field_import_email_address_chosen"}
`

Comment: @JamesRocky I've re-edited the answer. You have to use the explicit waits.